# Is the difference distribution table of AES S-box uniform?

Tags: aes, s-boxes, differential-analysis

I am studying about various block ciphers and their weaknesses, so I have a doubt about AES S-boxes, Is the difference distribution table of AES uniform ?

Comment: I meant difference distribution table of S-box of AES, like in DES the DDT of S-boxes  are not uniform

Comment: @TruthSerum A difference distribution table is what they call the table that contains sbox input difference/output difference/propagation probabilities.

Comment: Its a matrix with all possible input differentials as rows and corresponding output differentials as columns..As said by @Ella Rose it provides the probability of an output differential to specific input differencial. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference distribution table for the AES s-box contains mostly probability 2/256 differentials. However, there is a single probability 4/256 for each input/output difference. I uploaded a dump of the table [here](http://pasted.co/bcd10869) so that you can see.

The code used to produce this table [can be found here](https://github.com/erose1337/pride/blob/master/crypto/differential.py). Disclaimer: This is my personal github.

If by "uniform", you mean all values equal, the case is no. If you meant "differential uniformity", that is a term with a precise meaning:

From [this paper](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/projects/05-shash/diffuni.pdf), they define differential uniformity as "A mapping is called differentially uniform if for every non-zero input difference and any output difference the number of possible inputs has a uniform upper bound".

The AES s-box is a [differential 4 uniform function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/047.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ella Rose for your reply, i actually expected the DDT to be something like [this](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~cs236506/ddt/S1.html),its the DDT of S1 box of DES ...as we see it is not that uniform i.e. not every column (output diffrencial) has equal value(probability) for a particular row(input differencial)

Comment: well i see it has mostly 2/256 and one 4/256 in every row..can you please share the code to get that table ? and can i say AES Sbox DDT is more uniform than DES S-boxes DDT @Ella Rose ...Thank you in advance

Comment: @Abhinavsingh, Funfact: if you have too many ultra-low probability differentials, an [impossible-differential-attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_differential_cryptanalysis) may apply, like it did to SKIPJACK (didn't break it completely though).

Comment: @SEJPM thank you for your reply, I know about impossible differential cryptanalysis and it's been successfully applied on [7 rounds](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019004000936) of AES. What i wanted to be sure of is AES Sbox DDT  more uniform than DES S-boxes DDT ? and can we say AES Sbox is more secure towards differential cryptanalysis?

Answer (score 1):

AES S-box DDT is not uniform but it has a higher resistant to differential attacks than DES because of maximum probablity of input output pair of differential is 4/256.